# Finding two sets $A$ and $B$ such that $A \cap B = \varnothing $ and $\bar A \cap \bar B \neq \varnothing $

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

(This problem can be found in the book Real analysis by H.L. Royden (third edition), under the open and closed sets chapter.)

My take on this was taking $A = \{ x \in (0, +\infty)\}$ and $B = \{ x \in (-\infty,0) \}$. Then $A \cap B = \{ x \in (0, +\infty)\}$ and $  \{ x \in (-\infty,0) \}$ But by axiom of $\Bbb R$ a number is either positive or negative but not both thus $ A \cap B =\varnothing$

Likewise, $\bar A = \{ x \notin (0, +\infty)\}$ and $\bar B = \{ x \notin (-\infty, 0)\}$ then $\bar A \cap \bar B = \{ x \notin (0, +\infty)\}$ and $ \{ x \notin (-\infty, 0)\}$ so the only remaining option is $x=0$ and hence $ \bar A \cap \bar B \neq\varnothing $

Is my approach correct?

Comment: You're definitely missing something crucial to the problem, because it is trivial as it is stated: let $A=[1,2]$ and $B=[3,4]$. Then $A\cap B = \varnothing$ and $\overline{A}=A$, $\overline{B} = B$. Also, if $A = (0,+\infty)$ and $B = (-\infty,0)$, then $\overline{A}\cap\overline{B} = \{0\}$.

Comment: What does $\overline A$ stand for? Is it the closure of $A$, or the complement of $A$, or something else? (Not everybody has a copy of Royden't *Real Analysis* at hand.)

Comment: From the third paragrah, it means the complement.

Comment: No. Royden denotes the closure of $A$ as $\bar{A}$. It is in Proposition 10 on page 17, for instance.

Comment: I am assuming $\bar A$ is the complement of $A$ since so far in the chapter I have only been acquainted with open and closed sets, and points of closure.

Comment: @Luna145 page 17 of my book is the beginning of the chapter on Algebra of Sets, where Royden talks about Borel fields, algebras and sequences, but I could not find him using $\bar A $ as the closure of A...

Comment: @Rodrigoss I realized I have the 4th edition. It's a definition in that section. It's defined on page 17 in my book. Look around.

Comment: @Rodrigoss Looking at the book, it seems that the complement of $A$ is written as $\overset{\sim}A$ (defined in the section "Unions, intersections and complements"), and the closure of $A$ is written as $\overline A$ (defined in the section your exercise is from). For example, exercise 34.b. (in my version) uses both complement and closure in the same term. Moreover, I presume you're doing exercise 26? This question asks that $\overline A\cap \overline B$ is **not** equal to $\varnothing$.

Comment: @Vsotvep You are absolutely right, I mistakenly read the problem, I have edited my question.

Comment: In other words, the exercise is about closure, not about complements, so perhaps you want to edit your attempt at the exercise as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be any subset of some set $X$ and $B:=\overline{A}=X\setminus A$. Then $A\cap B=\emptyset$ and also $\overline{A}\cap\overline{B}=\emptyset$ since $\overline{A}=B$ and $\overline{B}=A$.
Moreover all examples are of this type since $\overline{A}\cap\overline{B}=X\setminus(A\cup B)$.

Answer (score 1):

If the exercise is about closures rather than complements as the comments suggest, you may want to consider the case $A = \mathbb{Q}$ and $B = \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$.